# Receive SMS with Java SE via GSM Modem (USB)?

Tags: java, text, sms

Can someone give me a code to receive SMS via GSM modem (USB) with Java? I have been searching for this code a while and I didn't find anything. Thank you

Comment: That question is too general. Please show us which APIs you have looked into and what hardware you are talking to.

Comment: The Hardware is a Huawei USB GSM modem.

Comment: And which API are you planing to use in order to talk to the modem via USB? Which protocol does that modem support?

Comment: SMSLib, but I have no idea how to do this.

Comment: SMSLib actually looks quite good. It seams like you need a [GSM Modem Gateway](http://smslib.org/doc/v4/GatewayFeatureMap) and than follow the [quick start guide](http://smslib.org/doc/v4/QuickStartGuide). If you have already tried that, what problems were you encountering?